# Count list not updating

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

Ive got a list showing how many times something has been commented on the problem is that this list does not seem to updated when something new is commented on. Any ideas how i improve this so the list is live and i can get the 20 most commented results.

What i have so far

Tables: **batsmen**: id, name
**comments**: id, title, comments, batsmen_id

Controller:

```
$batsmen = Batsmen::with('comments')->where('approved', '=', 1)->get()->take(25)->sortByDesc(function($commented)
{
    return $commented->comments->count();
});
```

Any idea how i make this so that the list updates after every comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try the following code ?

```
 $popularBatsmens = Batsmen::with('comments')
     ->withCount('comments')
     ->where('approved', '=', 1)
     ->orderBy('comments_count', 'DESC')
     ->take(20)
     ->get();
```